# "Additional information: Conversion from string "yes" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

I have program which requires user input like this:

```
Dim yesorno = InputBox("Do you have more credit cards?", "Thomas Shera")
    If yesorno = "Yes" Or "yes" Then
            Name = InputBox("You are a rich person, enjoy infinite credit card bill.")
    Else
        MsgBox("You poor person, you have only " & dcreditcards & " credit cards.")
    End If
```

The offending line two be specific:

```
If yesorno = "Yes" Or "yes" Then
```

This gives the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "yes" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Idea on fix this how, make "Yes" or "yes" not cause invalid error exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression (yesorno = "Yes" Or "yes") evaluates to (Boolean Or String) This causes exception. As a boolean is being compared to a string.

Try this code:-

```
Dim yesorno = InputBox("Do you have more credit cards?", "Thomas Shera")
If yesorno.ToUpper = "YES" Then
        Name = InputBox("You are a rich person, enjoy infinite credit card bill.")
Else
    MsgBox("You poor person, you have only " & dcreditcards & " credit cards.")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

It is:

```
If yesorno = "Yes" Or yesorno = "yes" Then
```

but it's better to use the right `StringComparison` in `String.Equals`:

```
If String.Equals(yesorno, "YES", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
```

you should also use `OrElse` instead which is a short-circuiting operator:

```
If yesorno = "Yes" OrElse yesorno = "yes" Then
```

otherwise both sides are evaluated always, even if the first already was `True`. That can be an issue with something like:

```
If yesorno Is Nothing Or yesorno.Length = 0 Then
```

This throws an exception even if the first expression already evaluated to `true`.